# Do all members of my family need separate UK visit visa applications?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

My mother made an application for a UK visit visa. We are four siblings and we all are travelling with her. Is it necessary to make separate application for all of us, or is only one enough? My mother has mentioned in the section that we are traveling with her.

Answer (score 6):

Everyone applies on a different application. Everyone needs to fill their own form (or have someone fill it for them), deposit their own fee, take their own appointment and everyone needs to pay for the appointment.

However the appointments for a family can be booked so they they attend together and the supporting documents can be linked together and will be sent to UKVI in one package by the VFS staff. For example: You do not need to print 5 copies of your mother's bank statements for each one of you. Just 1 copy is fine.

Of course your mother can pay for all of you on her card but she needs to pay for 5 applications and 5 appointments.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should accept the answer, not just write "thank you" in a comment.